# GitLFS migration with partial push

Tags: github, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I am trying to migrate history for a repo with large files (>100mb) into GitHub with the following command :

```
git lfs migrate import --include="*.gif"
git push origin master --force
```

Uploading LFS objects is successful. I get the following error:

> remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size (2.00 GiB) error:
> remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit

I tried to do pushes in chunks with `git push origin <commit>:refs/heads/master -f`. But one of the files seems to be in the history which was deleted in a later commit.

> remote: error: File /World/Maps/map_4.fbx is 337.34 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

This file is not getting tracked under: `git lfs ls-files`

I have already tried to manually add a line to the *.gitattributes*. Is there a way to successfully recognise this file or ignore it during push altogether?

Comment: I don't use Git-LFS, but in general your initial "import" to LFS needs to list *all* the files you want LFS-ized. You listed `*.gif`, but `World/Maps/map_4.fbx` ends in `.fbx`, not `.gif`. Remember that on the Git side, *every* commit contains a *full snapshot* of *every* file, and the function of the LFS wrappers (which are not part of Git: LFS is a separate program that "wraps" Git) is to hide the large files from Git's "eyes" so that Git never stores them at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure LFS like this:

```
git lfs track "*.fbx"
```

This will avoid the error that is related to your map_4.fbx file. Then try pushing to the remote repository again.

Answer (score 0):

I had to execute `git lfs push --all origin master` to add the additional files that were added later appended into .gitattributes. Partial push is now working.